# Get dropdown value selected using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop-down which is auto-built by jQuery. It's running fine.

When the user selects a value from the drop-down I would like to know what the value is.
Currently I'm using:

```
var employee= $('#emplist').find('option:selected').text();
```

but this seems to always return null.

Can someone tell me how to get the drop-down selected text to a variable.

My jQuery version is 1.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.val()`. Try below,

```
var employee= $('#emplist').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the **currently selected text**:

```
$('#emplist :selected').text();
```

**Or value**:

```
var value = $('#emplist').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
var employee= $('#emplist').find('option:selected').val();
```

Or the better way

```
var employee= $('#emplist').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var employee= $('#emplist').val()

      OR

var employee= $('#emplist').find('option:selected').val();
```